# Handle more than one returning value in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have following stored procedure

```
ALTER PROC spInParam
(
    @partyCode NVARCHAR(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @totalAmount float
DECLARE @setLoop int
DECLARE @setCNT int
print 'Party Code '+@partyCode;
set @totalAmount=(select TotalAmount from BillParticular where partyCode=@partyCode)
set @setLoop=(select count(TotalAmount) from BillParticular where partyCode=@partyCode)
SET @setCNT=0;
WHILE @setCNT<=@setLoop
BEGIN
print 'Total Bill Amt.'+CONVERT(nvarchar(50),@totalAmount);
set @setCNT=@setCNT+1;
END
return CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),@totalAmount)
END
```

In this stored procedure,

`select TotalAmount from BillParticular where partyCode=@partyCode` this query returns more than one values. (i.e. there are two TotalAmounts for particular `@partyCode`) how can i take them in loop?

I set while loop for this as shown in code.

This Stored Procedure compiled well. But while executing,  It gave me following error:

```
Party Code 0L036
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spInParam, Line 11
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

Please guid me what should be done in existing procedure.

Please tell me if i am making mistake anywhere.

Please help me.

**Sample Output:**

```
Party Code: 0L036
Total Bill Amount:1074432000
Total Bill Amount:2108208000
```

BillParticular table:

[image]

Edit:

```
DECLARE @partyCode nvarchar(50);
WITH records
AS
(
    SELECT  'Total Bill Amount : ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(50), TotalAmount) str_output
    FROM    BillParticular 
    WHERE   PartyCode = @partyCode
)
SELECT  'Party Code ' + @partyCode str_output
UNION ALL
SELECT  str_output FROM records
```

Returning `NULL`

Comment: Are you wanting to use a cursor or do you need the first item in the sub query?

Comment: yeah , i will , just a minute

Comment: @JW웃 please hav a look at edit

Comment: how about the records?

Comment: ok, will pate sceenshot

Comment: I have edited it. Please go through records for 0L036 PartyCode. They are two records for it. i want to print both of them as a TotalAmount @JW웃

Comment: how did you get `25054` and `87754`?

Comment: nope, that was just example. Sorry I edited it. @JW웃

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH records
AS
(
    SELECT  'Total Bill Amount : ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(50), TotalAmount) str_output
    FROM    BillParticular 
    WHERE   PartyCode = @partyCode
)
SELECT  'Party Code ' + @partyCode str_output
UNION ALL
SELECT  str_output FROM records
```

Comment: I have to put this in place of "select TotalAmount from BillParticular where partyCode=@partyCode"???

Comment: try executing the query first if it gives your output, otherwise i'll update it.

Comment: I have updated my question and put new query, its returning null

Comment: yup, got it, I had not passed 0L036 parameter for this query. I made it as set @partyCode='0L036'

Comment: It seems to be like 'views' in sql.